# .NET program ends suddenly

Tags: c#, .net, io

Currently I'm programming an application to record data. The data will be stored clustered to a file.

This data can be analyzed by the user or the program displaying the data. By analyzing large amount of data the program ends suddenly, i.e. there is no exception, any other error message or any process at the task manager just no more program.

By analyzing the program with perfmon I found lots of i/o (460 events/s and 15MB/s) at this moment as expected. Is there any limit reading data from different places of a file? (I'm seeking positions and read complete clusters.)

Comment: Therre could be a lot of problems, usually the runtime tries to write to the application eventlog when an unhandled exception occurs (if it can, which may not be the case if it does not have the persmission or there is an out of memory exception). You may find an entry that gives you more info. I also would recommend to add logging and an eventhandler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledExceptions in order to try to log exceptions that have not been handled

Comment: @Framil - is this a multi-threaded program?  If an unhandled exception occurs in a background thread .NET will kill the process in the manner you've described.  Get some try..catches in there and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're wrapping your code with a try..catch. Then set a break point in the catch. (@Paolo makes a good point, be sure the try..catch is in the thread that is doing the work.)

Also, you could try setting visual studio to break on all exceptions. "Debug" / "Exceptions" /   Select relevant "Thrown" check boxes.

Also, try checking the Event Viewer for some hints.

Finally, you can also do Debug.WriteLine or Trace.WriteLine in certain places (esp if running on a system w/o visual studio) and monitor output with [Sysinternals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)

Note: Be sure to make code production qual (i.e., add logging, program defensively, etc) after/while finding the source of the issue.

Comment: better to do some logging so exception details are recorder also when program runs with no debugger attached or no breakpoint is set.

Comment: Thx @Davide. Yup. That's production quality code. Just trying to give techniques to help get to the bottom of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use try..catch.

Subscribe to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledExceptions`.

Use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

Watch the process' working set.